# suggest a best way to do transformation of matrices in openGLES2.0?

Tags: performance, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vertex-shader

I am developing an OpenGLES2.0 application.Time to render the application is crucial thing for me.My application has both static and dynamic objects(moving pointers in dial).To improve the performance I want to reduce the computation burden on CPU. I want to compute the transformation matrices(translate,rotate,scaling) in the shader itself instead of computing them on CPU (only for dynamic objects).Is it advisable to do like this to improve the performance?

My vertex shader will look this

### vertex .c

```
int main() 
{

  if(static==0)   //for static rendering. Value sent from the app 
{
   gl_Position = mvp* vec4(vert,1.0); // MVP is calculated in the app and sent to shader 

}

  if(static==1) // for dynamic objects. Value sent from the app
{
 /* compute translated matrix
 /* Compute rotated matrix
 /* compute scaled matrix

  gl_Postion = mvp*vec4(vert,1.0); /* mvp is calculated in the shader 

}
```

}

calculation burden will be on GPU instead of CPU only in the case of dynamic objects.Will this improve time to render an application? I need a better FPS.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there is no precise answer to your question becouse it really depends on many factors. Particle systems for example tend to be very expensive becouse many calculations are often done inside a shader. So if you wanted to produce hundreds of particles it could be better to compute the mvp matrix for your dynamic objects on the CPU in order not to consume the GPU even more.

Basically, you should find a balance between your app processing on the CPU and OpenGL ES processing on the GPU and should consider what else would you like to render in your app in the future, how many etc...

There are however some brilliant tips that could help you optimize your shaders:
[Best practices for shaders](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html)

The interesting part for you begins from "Respect the Hardware Limits on Shaders" down to the bottom. A few things that could be improved in your shader:

- Use constants instead of immediate values in your shaders especially if you use the same immediate value a few times - the code might be less readable but surely more efficient. For example: create a const above your main()
  :

  ```
  const float ONE = 1.0;
  ```

and use it instead of direct 1.0 values.

- Branches and conditions are inefficient so it might be better to split your shader into 2 separate shaders:

For static rendering:

```
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = mvp* vec4(vert,1.0);
    }
```

For dynamic rendering:

```
    void main()
    {
        /* compute translated matrix
        /* Compute rotated matrix
        /* compute scaled matrix
        gl_Position = mvp* vec4(vert,1.0);
    }
```